# Localhost to local network port redirection on Windows

Tags: windows, http, port, owin

I have a server that listen on http://localhost:8001 and I want to make it available in the local network. Unfortunately I don't have access to the code and can't modify the above. It doesn't listen to requests from outside the network on port 8001.

I want to make it both available in the local network and change the port to 9001. Is there some tool or way to use OS functionality to solve this?

It's a Windows computer and I don't have admin rights.

Edit:

I noticed both `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` and `http-serv` on node works if I use 0.0.0.0 as the address but I don't have the power to modify this program so I wanted some way to redirect the calls in a bidirectional way

Edit2:

It's a OWIN Selfhosted .NET Framework Application.

Comment: Would it be possible to gain admin rights? Because it may need admin command prompt approval

Comment: It's possible but I wanted to avoid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply using your hostname should be enough.

You only need a reverse proxy in order to change the port.

This is easy enough [with a caddyfile](https://caddyserver.com/docs/quick-starts/reverse-proxy):

```
caddy reverse-proxy --from :9001 --to 127.0.0.1:8001
```

And a [caddy Windows release](https://github.com/caddyserver/caddy/releases) (like [`caddy_2.0.0_windows_amd64.zip`](https://github.com/caddyserver/caddy/releases/download/v2.0.0/caddy_2.0.0_windows_amd64.zip)) does not require any administration/elevated privilege: just use the `caddy.exe`. That is it. No setup, no installation, no registry modification.

Then:

```
https://<yourHostname>:9001
```